# Sturm's Theorem

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, algorithms

I'm using Sturm's Theorem in an effort to prove the existence of roots of some polynomials. Could someone recommend me a textbook with a detailed proof of Sturm's Theorem?

Comment: *Nathan Jacobson*'s **Basic Algebra I** should have a proof.

Comment: Google: Sturm theorem proof.  You will get lots of references.

Comment: @herbsteinberg a lot of terrible references

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem ... Try this.